how to implement a static vector in modern C++
I have an exercise and I could not understand what the assignment is talking about.
This is the text of the exercise

Provide static vector implementation in modern C++.
Class must be named static_vector and templated by the stored type
and vector's capacity. Class must provide methods:

capacity()
push_back()
size()
subscript operator [ ]

So far I came up with this code
template <class T, unsigned int C>
class static_vector{
public:
    unsigned int capacity() {return vect_capacity;}
    void push_back(T item) {}
    unsigned int size() {}
    T& operator[] (unsigned int index) {}

private:
    unsigned int vect_capacity;    
};

My misunderstanding is about the meaning of static and the development of the required functions.
Any help would be much appreciated.

you need to ask your tutor to explain what they require from you. Even if it would be clear to everybody else they should be informed that it isnt to you.

Ask whoever assigned the exercise to you. My best guess is "a vector that doesn't grow"

"and templated by the stored type and vector's capacity." means the size of the vector has a hard limit. And I suppose thats what they mean with "static", but eventually you need to ask them

Unfortunately I can not ask to a tutor since it was an online assignment.

there is no way to contact someone online? Perhaps time to find a better course

@vaeVictis About your existing code. You know the vector's capacity, it's C. So there is no need to also save the capacity in vect_capacity. So delete that member variable and rewrite capacity like this unsigned int capacity() const { return C; }

The name of a class is NOT a requirement. When you are asked to write a class, it should come with specifcations. E.g. does static mean, "size and content fixed at compile time", "fixed size at compile time", "should always be global" (I hope not). What types should it be able to hold (trivially constructible or not)....

You should just use C++26 inplace_vector.

push_back(T item) is certainly not correct for complex types (unecessary copying), investigate passing by reference or r-value reference. Also provide two overloads for operator[] (const and non-const version)

My best guess is that you need to write a wrapper around std::array<T, C>, count how many times push_back been called and assign the elements to your count position in the array. capacityshould probably just return C. But there is no way telling what your tutor had in mind.

It was a test for a company, stated like this, plain and not understandable at all.

"It was a test for a company" - then maybe the whole point of it was to trigger a discussion about specifications etc. And if that is so asking the right questions is the first step.

Well if it was a test for a company... I think THEY failed. A company should know how to give correct requirements ;) But yes I agree with Wohlstad also... it could be a test to see if you would blindly start coding or not ;)

@PepijnKramer   Not necessarily.  Clients - who provide the payment - often have unclear, ambiguous, contradictory, hand-wavy, requirements that they believe are simple, self-evident, and obvious.   An essential skill for quite a few developers is therefore being able to gently tease out and fill in details without offending the client, in order to have a starting point for development.   A company which has to deal with such clients may will be interested in finding developers who have those skills.

@Peter Depends :) Requirement gathering/documentation is a distinct role that in bigger (or better organized) companies are handled by specific people. These "finalized" requirements are then handed over to the actual developers. It is also for clients like this working agile may have a huge benefit. But yes... kind of out of scope for the original question too :)

Implementing static_vector: How Hard Could it Be?

The static_vector container is implemented as a dynamic-size array. It can store a variable number of elements of type T up to a fixed capacity N.
It allows to perform constant-time push and pop operations at the end, while requires linear-time insert and erase operations at any other position. Furthermore, it supports random access.
Implementation
The basic implementation consists of a plain array and a size. The former provides the storage, while the size maintains the number of elements that are actually contained. However, this design has an important limitation: as the container is constructed, the array, and therefore all its elements, are initialized.
A solution involves to replace the array od types T with a array of aligned storages, which have the same alignment and size of the above type. A possible implementation may be the form of alignas(T) char[sizeof(T)]. In this way, it is possible to create an uninitialized block of memory suitable to hold the objects of a certain type. Objects are created through a placement new and likewise are destroyed through an explicit destructor call.
Even if the seems ideal, there are some drawbacks. The most evident is the necessity to use reinterpret_cast to access the value. Indeed, the address of the storage must be taken and then the cast operation must be performed, which allows to convert the raw pointer to the specific pointer to type. Only referencing the pointer allows to access the actual object. This adds a layer of indirection. Furthermore, the use of such a operator can be dangerous: at run-time, it is easier to accidentally fall in undefined behavior (UB).
An alternative design is the following: the array of type T, coupled with a sentinel type, is wrapped in an union. The sentinel can be any default-initializable type, possibly small. For simplicity, char has been used. Then, the union is wrapped in another structure. The key point is the implementation of the default constructor, which must force the compiler to initialize the sentinel type instead of the array. In this way, as the container is constructed, the above default constructor is called, guaranteeing that all elements in the array remain uninitialized.
Example:
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class static_vector
{
public:
    using value_type              = T;
    using pointer                 = T*;
    using const_pointer           = const T*;
    using reference               = T&;
    using const_reference         = const T&;
    using size_type               = std::size_t;
    using difference_type         = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator                = T*;
    using const_iterator          = const T*;

    static_vector() = default;
 
    static_vector(std::initializer_list<value_type> il)
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(il.begin(), il.end(), this->m_impl.data);
        this->m_impl.size = il.size();
    }

    static_vector(const static_vector& x)
    {
        std::uninitialized_copy(x.begin(), x.end(), this->m_impl.data);
        this->m_impl.size = x.size();
    }

    static_vector(static_vector&& x)
    {
        std::uninitialized_move(x.begin(), x.end(), this->m_impl.data);
        this->m_impl.size = x.size();
    }

    ~static_vector() noexcept
    { std::destroy(this->m_impl.data, this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size); }

    static_vector& operator=(const static_vector& x)
    {
        const size_type len{x.size()};
        if(this->m_impl.size < len){
            auto it{std::next(x.begin(), this->m_impl.size)};
            std::copy(x.begin(), it, this->m_impl.data);
            std::uninitialized_copy(it, x.end(), this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size);
            tbis->m_impl.size = len;
        }
        else{
            std::copy(x.begin(), x.end(), this->m_impl.data);
            std::destroy(this->m_impl.data + len, this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size);
            this->m_impl.size = len;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    static_vector& operator=(static_vector&& x)
    {
        const size_type len{x.size()};
        if(this->m_impl.size < len){
            auto it{std::next(x.begin(), this->m_impl.size)};
            std::move(x.begin(), it, this->m_impl.data);
            std::uninitialized_move(it, x.end(), this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size);
            tbis->m_impl.size = len;
        }
        else{
            std::move(x.begin(), x.end(), this->m_impl.data);
            std::destroy(this->m_impl.data + len, this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size);
            this->m_impl.size = len;
        }
        return *this;
    }


    iterator begin() noexcept
    { return iterator{this->m_impl.data}; }

    const_iterator begin() const noexcept
    { return const_iterator{this->m_impl.data}; }

    iterator end() noexcept
    { return iterator{this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size}; }

    const_iterator end() const noexcept
    { return const_iterator{this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size}; }


    bool empty() const noexcept
    { return this->m_impl.size == 0; }

    size_type size() const noexcept
    { return this->m_impl.size; }

    size_type capacity() const noexcept
    { return N; }

    reference operator[](size_type n) noexcept
    { return this->m_impl.data[n]; }

    const_reference operator[](size_type n) const noexcept
    { return this->m_impl.data[n]; }


    void push_back(const value_type& v)
    {
        std::construct_at(this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size, v);
        ++this->m_impl.size;
    }

    void push_back(value_type&& v)
    {
        std::construct_at(this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size, std::move(v));
        ++this->m_impl.size;
    }

    void pop_back() noexcept
    {
        std::destroy_at(this->m_impl.data + this->m_impl.size - 1);
        --this->m_impl.size;
    }

private:
    struct impl
    {
        impl()
         : empty{}, size{} {}

        ~impl() {}

        union{
            char       empty;
            value_type data[N];
        };
        size_type      size;
    };
    
    impl  m_impl;
};


A static_vector is, a dynamically-resizable vector with compile-time fixed capacity and contiguous embedded storage in which the elements are stored within the vector object itself.
There was a proposal for this in May last year [open-std.org] and I hope it makes its way into the standard. For trivial value_types, the vector is fully usable inside constexpr functions.

FYI the code has not been tested properly. I will post any improvements when I'm done at the office.

Your implementation does not seem to be correct. Static vector should have only a storage for elements as a subobject, not an array of elements. In your case, the default constructor already creates N elements of type T, it should create none of them. Compare with Boost: https://godbolt.org/z/acP53P471.

I just realized. "...in which the elements are stored within the vector object itself". I'll rewrite my implementation later. For now I'll take it out.
